# Node.js and password security: three questions

Tags: node.js, express, security, bcrypt, password-encryption

I've never written a user auth system before and for this project I need to balance security with efficiency (meaning I can't spend hundreds of man hours working on the security end of this, but that I need to keep passwords and login info secure).

I'm using Node.js with the express framework and passport for authentication and sessions.

The research I've done so far shows three problems to solve. Before today I had literally no idea what if any common solutions exist for these problems, and a few hours of randomly pecking away at the research isn't giving me confidence in the completeness of the answers I've found.

The problems:

1. Do not store plain-text passwords unencrypted in a database
   (Possible answer: salt/hash the password ON THE SERVER and store the hash in the database.)
2. Do not pass plain-text passwords over non-secure http connection
   (Possible answers: A--Use Https ONLY for the authentication process. After that use http. B--Send a random salt to the user at the login page, hash the password client side, then un-hash and re-encrypt for database storage.)
3. Do not use weak encryption methods that GPUs can crack at 700,000,000 passwords per second.
   (Possible answer: bcrypt)

These are just the most sensible possible answers I've found in 3 hours of research. I have no idea whether these are sufficient, what their weaknesses are or what alternatives might be available. I'd appreciate any further insight (Also note: I'm not even sure--does https protect the password sufficiently as it is transmitted?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practices for security are many, but the idea is essentially the same:  hope for the best and expect the worst.  That explains your three problems:

1. Assuming someone gained access to your database, you don't want the possibility of passwords being compromised.  Hashed passwords guarantee that you cannot get the password from the hash.
2. This is to avoid from middle-man attacks.  A server could easily listen and record the password as it passes requests to and from your server.  Even if you don't think a middle-man attack is possible, hope for the best and expect the worst.
3. Use a long password that is easy to remember but difficult for others to guess.  Better still if you can limit the number of attempts to 3 every 5 minutes since that would require a multitude more time to crack.

Each of these three pivot on the idea either that someone *has* cracked your system and to do damage control or to make it near impossible to crack due to the sheer time it would take.  Performance is important but always *less* important than security.  Just use common sense mainly and don't compromise security based on assumptions, since that's the surest way to insert errors in your security.  In short, hope for the best and expect the worst.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question explicitly, (The question basically being--is there anything here that I haven't thought of, or any security measures I don't know about.)

Pretty sure, though, that the fact that you haven't named any specifically tells me what I need to know. I appreciate the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Brightstar, I apologize if I can't help you more than that.  Node.js is still very much in a development phase and while I'm sure security is important, most things being developed are important as well.  However, the fact that it is javascript means you're given potentially limited access to the server, contrary to other languages, which I'd imagine to be a big advantage and a point of security for the server.

Comment: That's actually not true at all, Neil. Node.js is not sandboxed like browser-side JS is. Security requirements with Node are similar to requirements with any other language. I still very much appreciate your reply, though. You did tell me what I needed to know.

Comment: I meant that contrary to typical languages which get converted into assembly and run, javascript is interpreted and therefore allows you to determine what a node.js program has and doesn't have permission to do.  It'd be like installing a Java Virtual Machine to explicitly deny disk write access to its programs.  It has that flexibility at least.

Comment: I see. Yes I suppose that's true. I guess that side of it never really occurred to me.